# Tracking statuses of instances of objects on different threads?

Tags: multithreading, events, status, consumer, producer

I am writing an image board scraper in my free time to teach me mostly about threading.  Currently I am using a producer/consumer type pattern to facilitate this effort.  However, I am running into a problem.

Right now, I have "queue processors" that observe and act upon specific types of thread-safe queues.  These queue processors poll the targeted queue every X seconds, and, if there is an item on the queue waiting to be processed, the queue processor de-queues that item, spins up a new thread with the item, and starts the thread.  On each thread, long-running methods are called (like connecting to the website and downloading the file).  In this manner, each item gets its own thread to run on.

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to report the status of each item while it is being processed on each thread.

For example, let's say we have main thread MT.  MT spawns child threads T1, T2, T3, T4, and T5.  On each thread is a corresponding object, O1...O5.  These objects can be in, say, three different states- S1, S2, S3- while it is being processed on its thread.

How can I report the status, S of each object O to the main thread MT when the status of object O changes?

I tried using events to report the status, but I'm encountering some wonky results around that.  I googled a bit about using threads and events, but didn't get very far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create another thread-safe queue which would be used to report status updates. Every time your thread changes its status, it would push a tuple/object containing the unique identifier of the job, the new status, the thread id and whatever else you deem necessary.

Once you've done that, you'll hit another problem: who will poll the queue? You could do it with your main thread in between its checks to the job queue but that could be ugly and could unnecessarily slow down the processing. You could also spawn another thread for doing just this but I'm guessing you need the status to be reported to the main thread so this doesn't help.

There's actually a better way to structure the program. Instead of having the main thread continuously poll the job queue and create threads (which is pretty expensive), you could instead create a thread pool and let the job threads do the polling themselves. This will leave the main thread free to poll the status queue waiting for whatever event it's looking for.

Here's some pseudo code to illustrate the concept:

```
main_thread()
    ...
    thread_pool = create_pool(get_core_count());
    thread_pool.execute(worker_thread);

    while(true)
         status = status_queue.pop_blocking();
         if (check_status(status) == WE_BE_DONE) 
             break;

    thread_pool.interrupt();
    ...

worker_thread()
    while(true)
        job = job_queue.pop_blocking();
        process_job(job);
        status_queue.push({job.id, thread_id, WE_DONE});
```

Essentially, what this does is create a thread pool that contains one worker thread per CPU core you have (an ok default to start with). Next up, it executes the function `worker_thread` in each worker thread (the function should be self-explanatory). The main thread then continuously checks the status queue for a certain unspecified event. Once that's occurred, it kills off the worker threads and resume executing the rest of the program.

Three things worth noticing in the example. First off, I recommend using a blocking pop call (`pop_blocking` in the example) over a manual polling implementation. It's a lot simpler to use and probably far more efficient. Next, I used `thread_pool.interrupt()` to kill off the job threads but it might not be the smartest way to do it depending on the language or library you're using. It's probably also a good idea to surround the `do_job(job)` call in a `try catch` statement if your language supports that kind of things.

Note that since your question is pretty light on details (the language being used for one), you'll most definitely need to adapt the solution to whatever you're trying to accomplish. This should still give you a good starting point.